# Почему не передаётся перменная в async функцию?

Tags: javascript

Есть код

```js
function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function myfunc() {

  fin_poluchateli_arr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: '111',
    surname: '111'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: '222',
    surname: '222'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: '333',
    surname: '333'
  }];

  var length_arr = 10;
  var step = 0;

  for (const poluchatel of fin_poluchateli_arr) {
    await (async function() {
      console.log('Цикл:' + poluchatel['id'] + ',' + length_arr); //Здесь пременная length_arr = undefined
      await sleep(1000);
    })();
  }
}

myfunc();
```

Не хочу выносить фунцию куда то за пределы. Хочу чтобы всё на виду было.
Нужно передать переменную в функцию `await async`, чтобы в консоли выводилось значение `length_arr`

```
await async function(length_arr)
```

не помогает.

Comment: в текущем виде все работает правильно. А вот в случае `await async function(length_arr)` вывод `undefined` вполне закономерен, так как при вызове не передается значение, следовательно аргументу присваивается `undefined`, который и выводится.

Comment: вы просто повторили вопрос. я и спрашиваю, как передать?

Comment: а как у функций передаётся параметр **при её вызове**? (это подсказка)

Comment: у какой функции? почему await (async function() { не видит значения переменных, даже если выше я делаё её глобальной  window.length_arr = 10;  ?

Comment: И почему тут переменная передаётся (если выполнить код). а у меня в браузере нет?

Comment: "у какой функции?" --- у `await (async function`  очевидно....................."не видит значения переменных"  --- что ты там мудришь одному богу известно, ты не показываешь что именно ты ещё делаешь....на данный момент Grundy вполне объяснил что происходит если ты ожидаешь на вход значение и объявляешь там параметр, но ничего не передаёшь................. "И почему тут переменная передаётся (если выполнить код). а у меня в браузере нет?" ---- ровно при таком же коде, как сейчас имеется или всё же при другом коде?

Comment: Обрати внимание, что в твоем же коде, в сниппете - все работает. Спрашиваешь ты при этом про другой код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -2):

Разобрался.
Всё написано верно. Переменной length_arr выше не передавалось значение. Еще раз проверил и всё заработало.